# Foursquare Venues with Facebook Post

Tags: android, facebook, foursquare

I have been searching feverishly for this and cannot find a solution.

According to this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/#placeobjects

I should be able to simply attach a foursquare venue URL to my "place" parameter as follows:

postParams.putString("place", "https://foursquare.com/v/ocean-taqueria-2/4a9752f1f964a520602920e3");

However. this crashes my app.  When i replace the foursquare URL with a facebook ID, it all goes well so I know the rest of the code is fine.  It just crashes when I use a foursquare URL.

There is nothing online that helps with this.

Any Help?

Comment: I think foursquare may have changed their metatags so they're not publishing the place tags anymore. If you do a view source on the foursquare page, you'll see that they're using "playfoursquare:location:latitude" and "playfoursquare:location:longitude" instead of the regular "place:location:latitude" and "place:location:longitude" you'd expect. See any yelp page for what the standard OG tags for place should look like.

Comment: Could you give an example?  I am kind of new to coding so I am not entirely sure what you mean by look at a Yelp Page.  DO you mean on the web?

Comment: Yes, on the web, and do a view source, and search for "og:", you'll see all the tags there.

Comment: I do see that they are using playfoursquare instead of place.

Does this mean that I cannot post foursquare links to facebook?  I see that Instagram is still able to do so.  How can i accomplish this then?

Comment: Hey Ming, Li  any help to how I can use foursquare places to post to facebook?

Comment: As is, I don't think you can.